# How do I make a listener that only returns the newest child added to the node?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write) show how to create a listener that listens to a node, but for my purposes this would be downloading too much data. I only want my listener to listen for when a new child is added to the node and return only that child. Is it possible to do this in Flutter? There might be a way to do this in the backend with JS/Typescript, but I'm looking for a client side way to do this.

```
//This returns all data at the node, but I only need new additions to the node
DatabaseReference starCountRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('posts/$postId/starCount');
    starCountRef.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
    final data = event.snapshot.value;
    updateStarCount(data);
});
```

Comment: Firebase is downloading only deltas behind the scenes.  You can view the deltas as deltas with QuerySnapshot.docChanges.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz can you please show me how I would write that using the example above?